# Roman armies seem to dislike fighting at night, Livy called it dishonourable. Skulking about. (Ennius, Scaenica, 254-7) Why?

Tags: ancient-rome

The query is in relation to Roman preference to erecting a secure camp at the end of each day and disparaging comments made regarding opposing forces who us e the night to their advantage. For example Quintus Fabius Maximus Verrucosus, refused to move from  his camp at night at Ager Falernus allowing Hannibal to escape.  Livy reported  “Not by ambushes and battles by night,” they thought, "nor by pretended flight and unexpected return to an enemy off his guard, nor in such a way as to boast of cunning rather than real bravery, did our ancestors wage war; they were accustomed to declare war before they waged it, and even at times to announce a battle and specify the place in which [p. 435]they were going to fight. The History of Rome, Book 42

Polybius XIII. 3 tells the same story of Roman warfare, citing it as the one remaining example of the practice formerly adhered to by the Greeks. “The ancients, as we know, were far removed from such malpractices (as treacherous dealings). For so far were they from plotting mischief against their friends, with the purpose of aggrandizing their own power, that they would not even consent to get the better of their enemies by fraud, regarding no success as brilliant or secure unless they crushed the spirit of their adversaries in open battle. For this reason they entered into a convention among themselves to use against each other neither secret missiles nor those discharged from a distance, and considered that it was only a hand-to-hand battle at close quarters which was truly decisive. Hence they preceded war by a declaration and when they intended to do battle gave notice of the fact and of the spot to which they would proceed and array their army. But at the present they say it is a sign of poor generalship to do anything openly in war. Some slight traces, however, of the ancient principles of warfare survive among the Romans. For they make declaration of war, they very seldom use ambuscades, and they fight hand-to-hand at close quarters”  Livy restates slightly later in Book 42 that Diodorus asserted “When the Romans announced that they had got the better of Perseus without recourse to arms, some of the senators tried to praise them. But what had happened did not please the eldest, but they said that it was not fitting that Romans should imitate Phoenicians, in such a way as to surpass their enemies through deceit and not through valour.”

Finally there is the previous mention that night fighting was seen as skulking around.

Comment: Are you asking why Roman armies seemed to dislike fighting at night or why Livy considered it dishonourable?

Comment: [On that night, the Gauls with stealth attacked the wall-tops of the citadel in the sleep-time, and on a sudden brought bloodshed on the sentinels](http://www.archive.org/details/remainsofoldlati01warmuoft/page/92).

Comment: In general, if you have the best army of the world for attacking head-on in an open field, you try to do that and value that as "good" and "just", and those who do otherwise (who happens often to be your enemy, that does not have any other good option against you) as bad, insidious (*insidias*). The same happened with the heavy armored mounted knights.

Comment: There seems t be a dislike for night work,  the romans did like to end the day tucked behind their palisades. There also seems to be some sort of concept of honourable/dishonourable tactics. Sneaky about at night was seen as not how a gentleman fights his battles.

Comment: The additional detail is a great improvement but I'm still not clear on exactly what you want to know.

Comment: Most humans dislike night work.  All humans dislike any strategy that doesn't play to their strengths.  I'm confused as to why this is a question... What is it you want to know?  What is the question?

Comment: Was there a tactical, moral or administrative bias against night battles. Was fighting at night seen as dishonourable? I'm guessing no, from the feedback it's a non question which is an answer in itself. .

Comment: Is there an example of an army that _did_ like fighting at night?

Comment: Please move comments to the he question

Answer (score 3):

The answer to why armies don't like fighting at night is plain and obvious: if you can't see, you can't fight well in a pitched battle.

The hangup seems to be whether it's dishonorable, but you're paying attention to the wrong part of Livy. If you read him more closely, you'll see what he's really talking about:

> **Not by ambushes** and battles by night, they thought, nor by **pretended flight** and unexpected return to an enemy off his guard, nor **in such a way as to boast of cunning rather than real bravery**, did our ancestors wage war; they were accustomed to declare war before they waged it, and even at times to announce a battle and specify the place in which they were going to fight.

Livy mentions three other examples aside from battling at night that the Romans found dishonorable. All three have to do with dishonesty. Livy is saying that the Roman ancestors didn't like the tricks and preferred to have their battles straightforward and honorable.

Night battles aren't really battles at all, but raids. The Romans have as an example two night raids that were highly criticized in antiquity: the sack of Troy and the sack of Rome, both involving sneaking in and killing people when they're asleep. This is what the Romans found distasteful, not the fact that something happened at night, but the fact that the night provided cover for conniving tactics as opposed to "manly" head-to-head bravery.

This is the reason that [Fabius Maximus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintus_Fabius_Maximus_Verrucosus#Fabian_strategy) was also criticized: his incessant running from Hannibal was brilliant, but not "manly" or "brave" and therefore incompatible with Roman values.

I should also point out that Fabius Maximus' [refusal to fight at night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Ager_Falernus#Night_operations) is unrelated to the above:

> **Fabius did not want to fight a night battle, fearing a Punic trick** to draw the Romans into a battle over broken, uneven ground, where Roman infantry would lose their edge as their lines would be broken, and communication would be hampered. Hannibal had previously hoodwinked and destroyed two Roman armies at Trebbia and Trasimene and the cautious Fabius did not want his army to be the third. Thus, although Hannibal still managed to trick the Romans, the Romans only suffered loss of face but not the loss of another army.

Comment: What has the final sentence got to do with your answer to the question?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The Romans disliked trickery and preferred open battle, which is why they didn't prefer to fight at night. The Fabian strategy was criticized by Romans for that same reason.

Comment: En summaire: There was a thread running through roman warrior culture that differentiated between open battles at an agreed time and place, sneak attacks and raids and tactics that used illusion and misdirection. The first was seen as preferable, was viewed as the the correct way for warring states to conduct themselves. An open victory in plain sight was seen as conferring legitimacy to the victory. The second was seen as legitimate up to a point while the third type of operations were seen as a sign of weakness or worse by an lesser opponent?

Comment: @SurusTours Sorry for the delay. Yes, you have it right. This appears in a variety of ways, from turning down ambush tactics to castigating those who murdered enemy generals in their sleep.